# How do I add debug unmanaged C++ project vs2010 called by a C# project in vs2017?

Tags: c#, debugging, symbols, visual-c++-6

I have an un-managed WIN32 dll that was written in VC++ 6 and called from a C# application. I have the dll project in VS2010 and C# project in VS2017. Both project can run through under debug/release mode successfully.

I found there was something wrong with the **arguments passed by C# to the dll** and thus wanted to debug the dll project. Here is what I did.

1. Open both VS2010 dll and VS2017 C# project
2. Change both projects' debugger type to mixed.
3. Change both projects' property to enable un-managed code debugging (it's called native code in VS2017)
4. Set break points at the argument calculation inside the dll where I want to debug and the C## function where I called the dll
5. For both vs2017 and vs2010, under Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols I define the path where .pdb files were generated for the dll project and Select "Automatically load symbols for all modules"
6. Start debugging C# code
7. In VS2010 C++ Project, select attach to process to attach the project to vs2017 exe; under select I chose both "managed" and "native"
8. The breakpoint of my c++ code showed as invalid since"no symbols have been loaded for this document"

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. Any suggestion would be really appreciated!